# Get path of sqlite database file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi everyone i can't set a relative path to open my database, the project is structured in this mood

```
projectname
db/acces.db
info/try.cs
```

This is the code inside try.cs with which i should open the database, obviously if I put the full path it goes:

```
 try {
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"data source="db/access.db")
      {
        conn.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand fmd = conn.CreateCommand()){
        fmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM 'test';
        fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
          Debug.Writeline("foo");
        conn.Close();
      }
    }
 catch (Exception e){
    Debug.WriteLine("Errors");
  }
```

I should take the path of the acces.db file, not complete but relative to my project, to be set in data source, how should i do?

Comment: Make sure the file is copied to the output folder.

Comment: I have made an answer. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    using System.IO;
var connection = "Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "db\\access.db")
    try {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connection)
              {
                conn.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand fmd = conn.CreateCommand()){
                fmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM 'test';
                fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                  Debug.Writeline("foo");
                conn.Close();
              }
            }
         catch (Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("Errors");
          }
```

Comment: Using `GetCurrentDirectory` is often sub-optimal, the current directory can be changed. I can't tell your project structure from what you show (e.g. is `db` a subfloor of `projectname`, and where does the EXE live).  You are likely to get a better starting point by getting the current assembly directory and going from there

Comment: It seems not to work, I get this `Data Source=C:\\Users\\mypc\\Documents\\tesrepo\\ Myapp\\testApp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\db\\test.db` , instead I should get something of type `Data Source=C:\\Users\\mypc\\Documents\\tesrepo\\Myapp\\testApp\\db\\test.db`

Comment: @codeboy you must set properties of the db file to "copy if newer" to copy dB file in execution path.

Comment: The problem isn't the path, it's the missing file. `data source="db/access.db"` will work if `Copy If Newer` is used. As for the correct location, given this is a Winforms application, it *shouldn't* be the exe's location (typically Program Files)

Answer (score -1):

You said you should get something of type `Data Source=C:\\Users\\mypc\\Documents\\tesrepo\\Myapp\\testApp\\db\\test.db`.

Here is how to get the correct path.

Project path：

```
Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.FullName;
```

Add the path you want at the end: For example, the address of the `123.mp3` file in the `music` folder here is:

[image]

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(projectDirectory + "\\music\\123.mp3");
```

//Get db address

```
string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.FullName;
string dbpath = Path.Combine(projectDirectory + "\\db\\test.db");
```

`dbpath` is what you want.

If you have any questions about my code, please add a comment below.

Updated：

You can import the updated file into the output directory through this operation.

[image]

Your path would work without any modification.

Comment: That's actually the *wrong* path. During deployment this will end up pointing to the application's parent directory, eg `Program Files` or `InetPub\wwwroot`. If the project targets .NET Core the current folder won't be just `bin/debug` either, it will be `bin/debug/net5.0` etc

Comment: You are right, my consideration is not so comprehensive. I updated my answer. Does it still have problems？